# Web Scraping masslottery.com using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, nested

I am trying to use beautiful soup to get all the keno numbers that came in ever. I mostly know how to do this but I am running into an issue. I need to get the game numbers and the numbers that came in for each game. However, using beautiful soup, I cannot figure out how to access these. I'll include a screenshot of the html, as well as a screenshot of what ive tried, as well as the link to the page I am inspecting.
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUIQ0.png)

I am trying to access `<div class="winning-number-ball-circle solid">` as you can see in that picture but all the html is nested.
I've tried
`soup.find_all('div',{'class':'winning-number-ball-circle solid'})`
and that does not work. Does anyone know how to access the inner elements?

Heres my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

mass = 'https://www.masslottery.com/tools/past-results/keno?draw_date=2021-06-17'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(mass)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')

div = soup.find('div',{'class','winning-number-ball-circle solid'})
print(div)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The data comes from an REST API call the browser makes by running Javascript. You need to make a request to that and then use the json returned

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.masslottery.com/rest/keno/getDrawsByDateRange?startDate=2021-06-17&endDate=2021-06-17').json()
```

Thanks to @MendelG for suggestion to use pandas for formatting:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.masslottery.com/rest/keno/getDrawsByDateRange?startDate=2021-06-17&endDate=2021-06-17').json()
pd.json_normalize(r['draws'])
```

Comment: You might want to add the option to use `pd.json_normalize` from Pandas for nicer formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
divs = soup.findAll('div',{'class':['winning-number-ball-circle','solid']})
for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

with soup.findAll you find all the divs with class names 'winning-number-ball-circle' and 'solid'
this returns a list.
With a for you display the text of these divs